React-Express: "Failed to Fetch Components" - Unable to Fetch API Data
I am working on a React.js project with an Express backend. I want to fetch components dynamically based on a parentName parameter, but my API calls fail with the following error:
Failed to fetch components.Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource.
CORS is enabled in my backend, and my database (MongoDB) is running fine. However, when I test the API in Postman or ThunderClient, I see "Connection Refused." When I log the database query results, it returns an empty array even though the data exists.
app.get('/getcomponent/:parentName', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { parentName } = req.params;
    const components = await Component.find({ parentName });

    if (!components || components.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'No components found' });
    }
    res.status(200).json(components);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching components:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch components' });
  }
});

This is my frontend part where im fetching data
 const { parentName } = useParams(); // URL param
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchComponents = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/getcomponent/${parentName}`);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch components');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setComponents(data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching components:', error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchComponents();
  }, [parentName]);

I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong here. Can someone please help me debug this issue?

Share your CORS configs

I suggest checking first whether CORS is handled in the index.js/app.js file of your backend.
Then confirm if parentName is the exact name of the field you're trying to fetch from the database. If this doesn't work, please share the detailed error you get.
